# Angular google map set cluster marker count

Tags: angular

i have using angular google map in my ionic 3 application.when the marker clustered it shows the default count of markers in cluter mareker icon that is okay but i need when the marker count increase above 9 it wil be displayed as 9+. is it possible for any one please share it will save my day.
   Thanks in advance.

### Actual output:

[image]

### Expected Output:

[image]

Comment: It is quite difficult to understand what exactly you are asking if you dont provide what you did. Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Actually I'm implement AGM map in my app when I zoom out it shows number of clustered marker count for example 10 I want to display as 9+ did you understand?

Comment: @GangadharJannu Actually I'm implement AGM map in my app when I zoom out it shows number of clustered marker count for example 10 I want to display as 9+ did you understand?